# Piece-wise Function with Variable

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have this piecewise function:

> $g(x)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{x^2-a^2}{x-a},  &  x\ne a \\
> 8,        &  x=a
> \end{cases}$

From there I broke it down to:

> $g(x)=\begin{cases}
> \frac{(x-a)(x+a)}{x-a}, & x\ne a \\
> 8,                      & x=a
> \end{cases}$

I have to find the $a$ that makes the function continuous, hence I took the limit of the piecewise function at $a$. I used the definition of limit definition of continuity, and got this:

> $$\lim_\limits{x\to a}(g(x))=g(a)$$
>
> $$\lim_\limits{x \to a}(\frac{(x-a)(x+a)}{(x-a)})=8$$
>
> $$\lim_\limits{x \to a}(x+a)=8$$
>
> $$((a)+a)=8$$
>
> $$2a=8$$
>
> $$a=4$$

Usually if I have the right answer but the wrong steps the problem is generally wrong: is my solution, and method to the problem correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is mostly correct. You proved that the function is continuous at $a$. However, to make it complete, I would also mention that the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}-\{a\}.$

Comment: Thanks but I am in AP Calculus AB, and the mere mention of set builder notation might show that I am ahead of the class (which is a bad thing). Even though I include that in my personal work, thanks a lot for your help.